# Evaluate $\int_{C} \frac{cos(z)}{z^{2}+1} dz$ where the contour C is the circle of radius 5 centred at 0.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I know the integrand is not analytic at $i$ and $-i$ however I am not sure how to go about this and I get stuck when I try to apply residue theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac{\cos z}{z^2+1}$ is an even function, the residues at the simple poles $z=i$ and $z=-i$ are opposite and by the residue theorem the given integral simply equals zero.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

The residues at $z=\pm i$ can be found by evaluating the limit

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}, z=\pm i\right)=\lim_{z\to\pm i}(z\mp i)\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve such integrals in which the region of integral contains all non analytic point of function is to evaluate $\int {1\over z^{2}}{f({1\over z})}dz$ which leads to evaluating $\int {cos({1\over z})\over {1+z^{2}}}dz$